# ESLint errors after upgrading from Vue 2.6.14 to Vue 2.7

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

We decided to upgrade Vue in our project from `2.6.14` to `2.7.x`.
Unfortunately, while following [the upgrade guide](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html), after bumping the Vue version to 2.7.8 (which is the latest right now), we are getting the following error:

```
./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/project/node_modules/vue/types/options'
Occurred while linting /path/to/project/src/main.ts:1
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:953:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at findModulePath (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-import-resolver-alias/index.js:99:27)
    at Object.exports.resolve (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-import-resolver-alias/index.js:75:10)
    at v2 (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/resolve.js:116:23)
    at withResolver (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/resolve.js:121:14)
    at fullResolve (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/resolve.js:138:22)
    at Function.relative (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/resolve.js:83:10)
    at remotePath (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js:801:379)
    at captureDependency (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js:803:380)
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js:811:107
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.ExportMap.parse (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js:806:427)
    at Function.ExportMap.for (/path/to/project/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js:797:201)
```

`main.ts` file is the file where we run some stuff before mounting an instance

```
const runApp = async () => {
  // ... do some stuff like analytics initialization

  const vm = await import('./app');

  vm.default.$mount('#app');
};

runApp();
```

and our `app.ts` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import { i18n } from '@/core/i18n';
import router from '@/core/router';
import store from '@/store/index';

import App from './App.vue';

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
// other plugins, directives, etc...

export default new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  i18n,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
});
```

If that may help, here are some packages with versions that may be important:

```
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.19",

    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
```

**Do you have any idea what may cause this error? Is this related to the ESLint or other packages? We tried different version combinations but with no success.**

Comment: Update `@vue/cli` to latest. Create a new vue2 project. Than compare the two projects' `package.json` files and edit your old project's file by matching the versions in the new project's file. Also remove any plugins you're not actively using in your own components. To see where a particular plugin is used, run `yarn why plugin-name`.

Comment: According to the upgrade guide, our `@vue/cli` version is fine.
Unfortunately, `vue create` CLI doesn't install the newest Vue 2.7 version, it's still 2.6.14, which means I can't compare it with our current upgrade setup. 

Although thanks for your advice and I will definitely use `yarn why`

Comment: In the test you created above, you can: update vue to 2.7.8, upgrade all `@vue/cli...` plugins to `~5.0.8`, remove vue compiler, add any vue plugins you want, starting with vuetify. Here's what I ended up with after adding vuetify and typescript: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/umv28z90/. No error so far. So even though your error comes from Vue, i'm guessing there's something off with your project's config. I can't help you more without a *runnable* [mcve].

Comment: Unfortunately, upgrading `@vue/cli...`, `webpack`, removing `vue-template-compiler` etc. didn't change anything. I guess it's something with the project's config...
Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @LovelyAndy I managed to upgrade, but I'm still not sure why it was happening. Probably something with `eslint-import-resolver-alias` package, because if I remember correctly, after removing `alias: { ... }` from `settings` in `.eslintrc.js` it started to work

Comment: Changing `vue-template-compiler` from "~2.6.11" to "~2.7.14" helped

Comment: @AlexanderGorg according to the upgrade guide, this shouldn't be a valid fix - "Upgrade vue to ^2.7.0. You can also remove vue-template-compiler from the dependencies - it is no longer needed in 2.7" or maybe something has changed later